# How to generate infinitly enemies in XNA?

Tags: c#, xna

I was developing a game using XNA frame work and here is my code 
I just want to generate infinite number of enemies 
here is my code please help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Audio;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.GamerServices;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Input;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Media;

namespace fight_in_the_sky
{
/// <summary>
/// This is the main type for your game
/// </summary>
/// 
public class Game1 : Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Game
{
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spritebatch;
    Texture2D  anim, background1, background2, enemy;
    Rectangle rect0, rect2, rectdst, srcrect, rect3, rect4, srcrect2, enemy_rect;
    float elapsed;
    float delay = 40f;
    int frames = 0;
    Random random = new Random();
    public Vector2 velocity;
    public Game1()
    {
        graphics = new GraphicsDeviceManager(this);
        Content.RootDirectory = "Content";
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferWidth = 800;
        graphics.PreferredBackBufferHeight = 600;
        IsMouseVisible = true;
    }


    protected override void Initialize()
    {
        // TODO: Add your initialization logic here
        rectdst = new Rectangle(0, 250, 115, 69);
        rect3 = new Rectangle(0,0,1280,720);
        rect4 = new Rectangle(1280, 0, 1280, 720);
        enemy_rect = new Rectangle(random.Next(800-94,800-47),random.Next(600-122,600-61),376/8,61);
        velocity.X = 3f;
        velocity.Y = 3f;
        base.Initialize();
    }


    protected override void LoadContent()
    {
        // Create a new SpriteBatch, which can be used to draw textures.
        spritebatch = new SpriteBatch(GraphicsDevice);
        background1= Content.Load<Texture2D>("starfield006");
        background2= Content.Load<Texture2D>("starfield005");
        anim=Content.Load<Texture2D>("shipAnimation");
        enemy =Content.Load<Texture2D>("mineAnimation");
        rect0 = new Rectangle(0, 0, 800, 600);
        rect2 = new Rectangle(0, 250,200, 100);

        // TODO: use this.Content to load your game content here
    }


    protected override void UnloadContent()
    {
        // TODO: Unload any non ContentManager content here
    }

    protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        // Allows the game to exit
        // if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        // this.Exit();
        // TODO: Add your update logic here
        elapsed += (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.Milliseconds;
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Left))
        {
            rectdst.X -= 12;
            if (rectdst.X < 0) { rectdst.X = 0; }
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Right))
        {
            rectdst.X += 12;
            if (rectdst.X > 700) { rectdst.X = 700; }
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Up))
        {
            rectdst.Y -= 12;
            if (rectdst.Y < 0) { rectdst.Y = 0; }
        }
        if (Keyboard.GetState().IsKeyDown(Keys.Down))
        { rectdst.Y += 10; if (rectdst.Y > 550) { rectdst.Y = 550; } }
        base.Update(gameTime);
        if (elapsed >= delay)
        {
            if (frames >= 7)
            { frames = 0; }
            else { frames++; }
            elapsed = 0;
        }
        srcrect = new Rectangle(115 * frames, 0, 115, 69);
        srcrect2 = new Rectangle(47*frames,0,47,61);
        if (rect3.X + background1.Width <= 0)
            rect3.X = rect4.X + background2.Width;
        if (rect4.X + background2.Width <= 0)
            rect4.X = rect3.X + background1.Width;
        rect3.X -= 5;
        rect4.X -= 5;
        enemy_rect.X +=(int) velocity.X;
        enemy_rect.Y += (int)velocity.Y;
        if (enemy_rect.Y >= 600 - 61 || enemy_rect.Y <= 0) velocity.Y = -velocity.Y;
        if (enemy_rect.X >= 800 - 47) velocity.X = -velocity.X;

    }



    protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime)
    {
        GraphicsDevice.Clear(Color.CornflowerBlue);

        // TODO: Add your drawing code here
        spritebatch.Begin();
        spritebatch.Draw(background1,rect3, Color.Azure);
        spritebatch.Draw(background2,rect4, Color.Azure);
        spritebatch.Draw(anim, rectdst, srcrect, Color.White);
        spritebatch.Draw(enemy, enemy_rect, srcrect2, Color.White); 
        spritebatch.End();
        base.Draw(gameTime);
    }
}
```

}

and here is a shot of my current output 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9Zzee.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Infinite is unpractical to build into a game, because sooner or later you would either run out of RAM or your screen would be too full to call it a game. Anyway, I can give you a basic idea to work with.
If you want your enemy count to keep increasing you can use a list and add an enemy every time you want one to appear

```
List<Enemy> enemies = new List<Enemy>;
```

In Update:

```
if(spawnTimer > spawnInterval && enemies.Count()<enemyLimit){
   enemies.add(new Enemy([rectangle of spawn location and image size]);
   spawnTimer = 0;
}
for(int i=0; i<enemies.Count();i++){
   if(enemies[i].defeated){  
   enemies.Remove(enemies[i]);
}
spawnTimer+=gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;
```

in Draw:

```
   for(int i=0; i<enemies.Count();i++){
       spritebatch.Draw(enemy, enemies[i].Rect, srcrect2, Color.White);
    }

class Enemy{
   public Rectangle Rect{get;set;}
   public bool defeated{get;set;}
   public int Health{get;set;}

   public Enemy(Rectangle rect){
      Rect = rect;
      Health = 100;
      defeated = false;
   }

}
```

Comment: Try to avoid adding and removing things to a list during a game as it will lead to extended pauses during GC.  Consider using a fixed list and marking items as "dead" so that they can be recycled.  [More...](http://www.amazon.com/Game-Engine-Architecture-Jason-Gregory/dp/1568814135)

Comment: give me more details about this line    enemies.add(new Enemy([rectangle of spawn location and image size]);

Comment: enemies is a generic list containing of enemy objects. "Add" adds an object into a list. "new Enemy()" creates an enemy object. The square brackets is just a constructor argument. Right now you use enemy_rect as a drawing rectangle , the argument in square brackets is the same kind of rectangle just at random coordinates, since I assume when generating multiple enemies you don't want them to spawn at the same location.

Comment: I got this output but no movements http://imgur.com/cfacJiL

Comment: That is because my code is drawing enemies using Rectangles inside Enemy Objects. find "enemy_rect" in your code and replace it with a loop where you modify enemies[i].Rect instead.